# how to get total number of pages in PdfQuery

Tags: python, pdf

I'm trying to get how many pages a PDF has.  My attempt was to do this:

```
   pages = pdf.doc.catalog['Pages']
   print pages
```

but this prints `<PDFObjRef:2>`.

Answer (score 4):

Got it finaly

```
pdf.doc.catalog['Pages'].resolve()['Count']
```

It respond with number of pdf pages